# How to have a div with a scrollable div inside not scroll past a certain point based on window size?

Tags: css

I might butcher describing the issue here, still new to all this.

I have a div with the ID "content" which has a scrollbar in it depending on the content length.  That's inside another div with the ID "contentArea". Now I want the contentArea div to be a fixed size so that way I cant have the content div scrollable if it's larger than the contentArea size.

With my code, it might seem fine if the browser window is at full size or a certain size but the smaller you get, the contentArea div can be scrolled past the h1 with a scrollable dive inside of it.  So you get something such as this:

[image]
Pretty much if you click outside the scrollable div, you can scroll that other div and it goes past the logo area which is not what I want.  I only want the div inside to be scrollable.

Really what I want is something like this in my wireframe:
[image]

So anything inside that box is scrollable and hides under the logo area sort of.  This is why I had two divs, one where it's scrollable inside the div that is a certain size in a fixed position.  I had a friend look at it and he added a few changes in the css, one of it being a height of 50% in contentArea, and that works if your window is a certain size, any smaller and you run into the same issue where you can scroll it past the logo area.

What am I doing wrong here? Also is there a better way of achieving this result? I feel that perhaps I might not need to have one div inside another maybe?

```css
    html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #3a3a3a 50%, #1b1b1b 100%);
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0px;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: Eina01Regular;
  src: url(/fonts/Eina01-Regular.ttf);
  font-weight: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: Eina01SemiBold;
  src: url(/fonts/Eina01-SemiBold.ttf);
  font-weight: bold;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: Eina01Bold;
  src: url(/fonts/Eina01-Bold.ttf);
  font-weight: bolder;
}
/* Use this for image background */
/* @media (max-width: 7680px) {
  body {
    background: url(/background.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    resize: both;
    overflow: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
} */
h1{
  font-size: 60px;
}
#topBar {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  height: 61px;
  top: 0;
  position: sticky;
  /* box-shadow: 0px 2px 15px #000000; */
}

#nav {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 198px;
}
#navLinks {
  font-family: Eina01SemiBold;
  font-size: 15pt;
  color: #707070;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#navLinks li {
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 80px;
}

#navLinks a {
  color: #707070;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#navLinks a:hover {
  color: #9b9b9b;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-underline-offset: 2px;
}

#logoArea {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 130px;
  position: fixed;
}
/* Transition effects from swup */
.transition-fade {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 150ms;
  transform: translateX(0);
  transform-origin: left;
}

html.is-animating .transition-fade {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(100%);
}

html.is-leaving .transition-fade {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(0);
}

/* End of transition effects from swup */

#contentArea {
  margin-top: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 130px;
  margin-left: 130px;
  margin-right: 130px;
  position: fixed;
  height: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

#content {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

#content::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 5px;
}

#content::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: black;
  border-left: 2px solid transparent;
  border-right: 2px solid transparent;
  background-clip: padding-box;
}

#content::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #000000;
}

#bottomBar {
  background-color: white;
  position: fixed;
  height: 61px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

#footerContent {
  margin-left: 130px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
    <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script defer src="node_modules/swup/dist/swup.min.js"></script>
    <script defer src="script.js"></script>
    <title>Living Dreams - Projects</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="reset.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="topBar">
      <div id="nav">
        <ul id="navLinks">
          <li><a href="/index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="/projects.html">Projects</a></li>
          <li><a href="/about.html">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="/contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="logoArea">
      <img src="/logo.png" />
    </div>
    <div id="swup" class="transition-fade">
      <div id="contentArea">
        <div id="content">
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec
            ullamcorper lacus elit, nec dictum lacus aliquet vitae. Pellentesque
            habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac
            turpis egestas. Morbi tincidunt diam ut purus consequat tempor. Sed
            vitae nisi ut ipsum gravida scelerisque. Aliquam vitae tortor sit
            amet diam facilisis euismod quis non arcu. Aenean gravida arcu mi,
            at eleifend libero volutpat id. Donec imperdiet erat ac felis
            tempor, sed hendrerit nunc hendrerit. Vestibulum metus felis,
            bibendum nec faucibus in, fermentum nec lacus.
          </p>
          <br />
          <p>
            Vestibulum viverra, neque ut maximus sollicitudin, risus mi mattis
            odio, ut luctus erat augue quis nunc. Nam quis blandit lacus.
            Vivamus orci arcu, lobortis placerat mi ac, porta mattis diam.
            Aliquam quis efficitur neque, in euismod ipsum. Ut dictum mattis
            ante, vitae tincidunt massa interdum eu. Aenean vitae arcu ut lectus
            rhoncus ornare et et erat. Suspendisse iaculis euismod ante, eget
            accumsan nunc. Morbi euismod magna in euismod viverra. Phasellus
            ullamcorper ipsum quis lacus cursus dictum. Quisque mollis fringilla
            ultrices. Curabitur in elit odio.
          </p>
          <br />
          <p>
            Aenean vestibulum lacus et lorem faucibus, vitae pretium quam porta.
            Curabitur posuere erat eu interdum consequat. Aenean at semper est.
            Nullam at molestie turpis, ac luctus lorem. Etiam magna risus,
            vehicula in consectetur id, sagittis id mauris. Quisque enim lorem,
            ullamcorper sed maximus sit amet, suscipit eu mauris. Donec ac
            tempor ligula, eget semper neque. Etiam lacinia felis at nulla
            iaculis rhoncus.
          </p>
          <br />
          <p>
            Duis luctus risus eu interdum euismod. Vivamus ut nulla id ante
            pulvinar condimentum. Donec facilisis leo at sollicitudin vulputate.
            Suspendisse placerat, enim et congue pharetra, dolor eros ultricies
            velit, vitae pellentesque justo eros ut velit. Pellentesque habitant
            morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis
            egestas. Ut nec lorem rhoncus, ornare odio ut, egestas urna. Quisque
            rutrum sit amet velit vel tristique. Aenean in condimentum diam.
            Fusce vitae orci eros. Pellentesque consequat dapibus aliquam. Fusce
            sit amet sapien lacus. Sed dui neque, cursus non nunc id, aliquam
            condimentum ligula. Phasellus sed sagittis ex. Integer facilisis
            nisi lacus, vitae fermentum lacus sagittis non.
          </p>
          <br />
          <p>
            Fusce eleifend mauris non ex convallis, ut tincidunt ligula laoreet.
            Nulla tristique nisi scelerisque scelerisque pretium. Vestibulum
            bibendum odio at eleifend semper. Praesent sit amet tortor
            facilisis, interdum lacus ut, condimentum tellus. Nunc risus mi,
            varius a interdum sit amet, facilisis quis felis. Phasellus molestie
            eros tortor, ut venenatis orci molestie eget. Suspendisse potenti.
            Nulla id rhoncus nisi. Curabitur pretium tincidunt ipsum at egestas.
            Integer maximus diam vitae turpis viverra, ut volutpat odio
            molestie. Mauris et pretium tortor. Nam sapien sem, feugiat non
            lectus a, interdum faucibus eros. Quisque eget nisl ultricies, porta
            eros sit amet, congue metus.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="bottomBar">
      <div id="footerContent">
        <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/49030813/" target="_blank"
          ><img src="linkedin.png"
        /></a>
        <a href=""><img src="behance.png" /></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Update: I tried having the content div without the contentArea div and that, unfortunately, didn't work out for me either.  This one has me stuck.  Should this have been in an iframe instead?  Is using iframe still a thing these days, or is that just frowned upon?  I'm just trying to do it in a way that's ideal with today's standards. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, not sure if this is an ideal way or not but for anyone else interested in this...

So pretty much contentArea height was at 50%, all the other divs were using exact pixel count for margins, positioning, and whatnot.  Making them all percentages instead of exact pixel values fixed the issue.